# Reemplazar valor en array PHP y llamarlo luego

Tags: php, array

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente.

Mi objetivo es reemplazar los valores de todas las frutas para incrementar en un 5% el precio:

```
// precios originales

$precios = array (

    "frutas" => array (

"manzanas" => 15,
"peras" => 5,
"naranjas" => 3,
),

"verduras" => array (
  "clave" => 15,
  "clave2" => 5,
  "clave3" => 3,
)

);

// Los precios de frutas suben 5%

foreach ($precios['frutas'] as $clave => $valor) {
  $nuevovalor = $valor*5/100+$valor;
  $valor = ceil($nuevovalor);
}

// los precios de las verduras suben un 3%
foreach ($precios['verduras'] as $clave => $valor) {
  $nuevovalor = $valor*3/100+$valor;
  $valor = ceil($nuevovalor);
}
```

Mi idea es usar la función `array_replace` pero hasta acá llego, nada de lo que hice parece funcionar para reemplazar los valores con los nuevos precios, esto en caso de que los nuevos precios estén bien resueltos con esa función, tu idea será bienvenida, saludos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefiero modificar el array sobre sí mismo en lugar de usar `array_replace`. Sin embargó, te dejé ambas soluciones. [Prueba en IDEONE](https://ideone.com/U0xpyI)

```
<?php

$precios = array (

    "frutas" => array (

"manzanas" => 15,
"peras" => 5,
"naranjas" => 3,
),

"verduras" => array (
  "clave" => 15,
  "clave2" => 5,
  "clave3" => 3,
)

);

var_dump($precios);

// Los precios de frutas suben 5%

$tmp = array();

foreach ($precios['frutas'] as $clave => $valor) {
  $tmp[$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.05));
//  $precios['frutas'][$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.05));
}



$precios=array_replace($precios,array('frutas'=>$tmp));

$tmp = array();
// los precios de las verduras suben un 3%
foreach ($precios['verduras'] as $clave => $valor) {
  $tmp[$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.03));
 // $precios['verduras'][$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.03));
}
$precios=array_replace($precios,array('verduras'=>$tmp));


var_dump($precios);

?>
```

comentarios:

`=` es la forma de realizar asignaciones en el sentido "tradicional": lo que está a la derecha del `=` se asigna a lo que está en la izquierda; mientras que `=>` funciona al contrario y se usa en ciclos "for". por otro lado, al multiplicar un valor por un valor decimal obtienes el porcentaje, siendo 0.05 equivalente al 5% y 1 equivalente al 100%. al sumar ambos valores tengo el 105%, lo que es igual: un incremento del 5%.

Comment: Gracias!!, ésta es la clave

$tmp = array();
foreach ($precios['frutas'] as $clave => $valor) {
  $tmp[$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.05));
//  $precios['frutas'][$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.05));
}
$precios=array_replace($precios,array('frutas'=>$tmp));

No se me hubiera ocurrido esto, aún dp de mirar 15 tutoriales y leer, oye qué recómendas para aprender PHP.

Comment: 1. deje dos soluciones en el codigo, una con el array_replace el que se utiliza un vector temporal y otra en el que no se necesita array_replace (que es la linea que se encuentra documentada dentro de cada ciclo).
2. creo que tu problema no es tanto de php sino de fundamentos de programación y el desarrollo de la lógica, te recomiendo que resuelvas ejercicios de programación.

Comment: 1. Si, tengo que reemplazar el valor del arreglo dentro de 2 días, por ahora va el arreglo original sin array_replace 2. Qué te parece esto https://sites.google.com/a/incap.edu.co/cursos-arturo-annear/logica-y-fundamentos-de-programacion/archivos-para-descargar

Comment: * ni el cambio sobre si mismo, gracias.

Comment: tengo una pregunta que me esta haciendo mucha atención.
`$precios['frutas'][$clave]=ceil($valor*(1+0.05));` cómo es que ese `=` asigna en tu sintaxis el valor del arrelo y no usas `=>` . y el cálculo matemático 1+.05 pues no se me habría ocurrido ¿cómo lo desglozas?.

Las 2 opciones funcionan, gracias otra vez.

Comment: he agregado un comentario a la respuesta, resolviendo tus dudas.

Answer (score 9):

Te complicaste mucho. En vez de recorrerlo con un `foreach`, recorre el arreglo con un `for` y podrás tener el índice el arreglo para así manipular sus datos.

Con `foreach` puedes hacerlo pero debes declarar una variable incremental para usarla como índice. Además no uses el nombre de variables como índices, porque no podrás recorrerlos dinámicamente:

```
// precios originales

    $frutas = Array();
    $frutas[] = Array('nombre' => 'manzana, 'precio' => 15 );
    $frutas[] = Array('nombre' => 'peras, 'precio' => 10 );
    $frutas[] = Array('nombre' => 'naranja, 'precio' => 25 );


    for($i = 0 ; i < sizeof($frutas); $i++)
    {
      $frutas[$i]['precio'] = $frutas[$i]['precio'] + (0.05 * $frutas[$i]['precio']);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Luis gracias por tu respuesta pero no entiendo ese esquema para un arreglo, llevo 2 días con PHP solamente. Sí entiendo el For, pero el esquema completo de mi arreglo es el que puse en el ejemplo, ¿podés plantear tu opción con esa manera?. Luego, el precio final, valor, remarcado con el aumento es llamado por otro arreglo como precio_final, por ejemplo "precio_final" => $precios['frutas']['manzanas']

Comment: Es que el arreglo que plantiaste no usa indices numéricos y ese es el problema para trabajar con el dato. tu indice se llama 'manzana' ... ningún programa podrá recorrer un indice llamado manzana ya que no podrá ser dinámico me entiendes? de hecho en cualquier lenguaje de programación es recomendable usar números en los índices de los arreglos.

Comment: Entiendo, el tema es que MercadoPago, el sistema de pagos que uso para mi sitio, usa los arreglos con esa estructura que tu te ocupas mucho en remarcar que es incorrecto usar:

$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "TITULO DEL PRODUCTO",
            "currency_id" => "ARS",
            "category_id" => "CATEGORIA DEL PRODUCTO",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "unit_price" => $precios['frutas']['marca01']
        )
    )
);

Pero en el ejemplo que te pasé, con mi poca experiencia, funciona, pero no del todo. Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: El ejemplo que me mostraste usa arreglos numéricos. no es igual al arreglo que creaste, debes comprender mejor como declarar arreglos antes de usarlos. Haber mira 'manzana' es un indice y no una propiedad... 'title' es una propriedad pero su indice es un número. 'items' si es un índice, pero está bien aplicado ya que se trata de un solo valor en el arreglo (no es dinámico como los productos)

Comment: Sí ya está solucionado, gracias Luis, qué recomendás (sitio o recurso) para aprender PHP, estoy a los saltos entre tutoriales y videos, los agradezzco mucho pero quisiera aprender más.

Comment: Aquí está todo lo básico de php "http://www.phpya.com.ar/index.php?inicio=0" pero terminando la parte básica, debes dar un salto a usar frameworks php, como codeigniter o laravel...

Comment: @JavierSal te recomiendo que para aprender o iniciarte con algun lenguaje de programacion aprendas primero lo bueno, lo malo y lo feo del lenguaje y luego profundices con los frameworks y las "bondades" que ofrecen para facilitarte el trabajo con el lenguaje. Esta es una forma que te permite aprender y ser mas habil por sobre comenzar a aprender en base a frameworks, segun explican [aca](http://amasad.me/2016/01/03/overcoming-intuition-in-programming/).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza voy a leer tu enlace. Qué recomendás leer para estudiar PHP (mas abajo me recomendaron lógica de programación más que php).

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAguileraClarke sí lo conocía gracias, los frameworks para más adelante.

Comment: @JavierSal si estás iniciando en el mundo de la programación, lo mejor sería aprender algoritmos y lógica de programación, independiente al lenguaje de programación que escojas. En mi opinión, buenos lenguajes para aprender los conceptos básicos son Ruby y Python, también se enseña Java, PHP no es malo sino que no es lo común pero no significa que no pueda ser tu primer lenguaje. Ahora, lo segundo que te recomiendo es crear proyectos pequeños y culminarlos, eso te dará bastante experiencia y ayudará a que desarrolles habilidades que quizás no sabías que tenías

Comment: Estoy en un un proyecto pequeño a mediano que suena grande, luego de usar prestashop y wordpress estoy optando por desarrollar una tienda de cero con un sistema arcaigo editando PHPs a mano y me compliqué como dijisté antes, pero así aprendo. Estoy leyendo esto https://sites.google.com/a/incap.edu.co/cursos-arturo-annear/logica-y-fundamentos-de-programacion/archivos-para-descargar

Answer (score 4):

Puedes aprovechar los beneficios de PHP 5.5 y utilizar [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) y un [lambda](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php). El código se simplifica bastante:

```
$precios = array (
    "frutas" => array (
        "manzanas" => 15,
        "peras" => 5,
        "naranjas" => 3,
    ),
    "verduras" => array (
        "clave" => 15,
        "clave2" => 5,
        "clave3" => 3,
    )
);
//funcion definida con lambda
$agrega_porcentaje = function($n) { return 1.05 * $n; };
//utilizamos array_map para aplicar la funcion de mapeo en cada array
array_map($agrega_porcentaje, $precios['frutas']);
array_map($agrega_porcentaje, $precios['verduras']);
```

Inclusive, la segunda parte del código se puede simplificar aun mas, en caso que tengas otro tipo de elemento con su precio además de frutas y verduras:

```
//funcion definida con lambda
$agrega_porcentaje = function($n) { return 1.05 * $n; };
//utilizamos array_map para aplicar la funcion de mapeo en cada array
foreach ($precios as $elemento) {
    //sabemos que cada $elemento es un arreglo
    array_map($agrega_porcentaje, $elemento);
}
```

Comment: Voy a estudiar esta opción aunque en mi servidor tengo la version Version 5.4.35, lo voy a probar en phptester, gracias Luiggi

Comment: @JavierSal los lambdas están soportados desde PHP 5.3

Comment: `$agrega_porcentaje = function($n) { return 1.05 * n };` unexpected '}' 
entonces pongo ";" despues de la n del return, obtengo
 `Use of undefined constant n - assumed 'n'`

Comment: @JavierSal lapsus brutus mío, olvidé agregar `$` a la variable `n`. Ya corregí el código.

Comment: jojoo, `syntax error, unexpected '}'` falta el `;` luego de la `$n`. 

Lo corregí, la función corre pero no cambia los valores